# Adding a value to a map in typescript

Tags: typescript

I must be missing something here. I try to put a value into a map but it doesn't want to work.

```
const tempMap = new Map();
tempMap.set("bla", "bla");
console.log(tempMap)
--> output: {}
```

Can someone explain to me why it is like that? Shouldn't the output have the added value in it?

[Try it yourself in the playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCoASMFmgY7p7ehCTkVOle4jUMdRLYTqCc8LEZzCZmoNJODPHFZZXVtZYYkAAeRJTInDQS8po%20rf40gnjbDKv8LqD2jpbYoACqAEoAMsK7sUmxkGSCc%20VVQQuaTwVb1UBrDYULY7PagbgUZLJH6QbYmJAECjuMigZEMVDsJzCFLNXxtajBdw0VCIAgAWQYBFAAF5BpAJKAGQQABQASgA3IoafTGQFBJBUNyAETSRhS-gyuUCxQITiCeDuALQeDMbnCrm84LFHANDxkLyIeADBgg9jU%206MTjMdgMZiQfiwaDqRI2%20B6EReKUAUVWDFp7kEUqSOKl4AcqAA5MIAHLsqVBFQAeW%20ZF24v4buOqEcClc0jwoCclp0oyw%20hQCEQMOEV2%20kit0REBg4OO6LDYXG4QRKQA)

Comment: The value is added. Try logging `Array.from(tempMap.keys())` or `Array.from(tempMap.values())`

Comment: `console.log(tmpMap.get("bla"))`

Comment: `console.log(tempMap.has("bla"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class itself won't export any values, use should use the [API](https://howtodoinjava.com/typescript/maps/)

You want to do something like this:

```
let tmpMap = new Map();
tmpMap.set("bla", "bla");
console.log(tmpMap.get('bla')); // bla
```

You can also iterate in `tempMap.keys()` or `tempMap.values()` like @Evan already commented.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) looks like I've still got some way left with Typescript and how these types really work.

Comment: In the end I like to serialize this map to session storage e.g. ``sessionStorage.setItem("some_key", JSON.stringify(tmpMap));``.

I could get all the values, but do you have a suggestion on how to serialize the object as a whole?

Comment: If you want to use the object itself, maybe `Map` is not what you looking for. You can create an custom interface and use https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used the `Record` type for my purpose. Which is a kind of dictionary type.